# EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on ArticlesService

Tags: angular

[This is a Planker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iFYtlbDte83umKgiUcTl?p=preview)

i'm tring to get whole article text from json file by press a button "more".
When i press "more" button i get an error "EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on ArticlesService".

article.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-material/all';
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';
import {ArticlesService} from './article-service';
import {ArticlesDetailComponent} from './article-detail';

@Component({
 selector: 'articles',
 providers: [ArticlesService,HTTP_PROVIDERS],
 template: `
 <md-content class="md-padding" layout="row" layout-wrap layout-align="center start">
```

```
  <img src="{{article.article_img}}" class="md-card-image" alt="Grass">
  <md-card-title>
    <md-card-title-text>
      <span class="md-headline">{{article.article_title}}</span>
    </md-card-title-text>
  </md-card-title>
  <md-card-content>
  {{article.article_content}}
  </md-card-content>
  <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
    <button md-button (click)="gotoDetail()">More</button>
  </md-card-actions>
</md-card>
</div>
</md-content>`,
 directives: [MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES,ArticlesDetailComponent]
})
  export class ArticlesComponent {

  constructor(private _articles:ArticlesService,private _router:Router) {}

public articles;
private errorMessage;
 ngOnInit() { this.getArticles();}

  getArticles() {
  this._articles.getArticles()
  .subscribe(articles =>
  this.articles = articles,
  error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
 gotoDetail() {
   this._router.navigate(['ArticlesDetail', { id: this.articles.id }]);
 }
}
```

and articles-detail.ts

```
import {Component,OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-material/all';
import {ArticlesService} from './article-service';
import { RouteParams } from 'angular2/router';


  @Component({
  selector: 'articles-detail',
  providers: [ArticlesService,HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  template: `
     <p>Detail</p>
                `,
   directives: [MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES,ArticlesService]
      })
  export class ArticlesDetailComponent implements OnInit {

     constructor(private _articles:ArticlesService,private _routeParams:                RouteParams) {}

 public article;

  ngOnInit() {this.getArticle();}


  getArticle() {
let id = +this._routeParams.get('id');
  console.log(id);
    this._articles.getArticle(id)
   .then(article => this.article = article);
     }

 goBack() {
window.history.back();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the service into the `directives` attribute of the `ArticlesDetailComponent` component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'articles-detail',
  providers: [ArticlesService,HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  template: `
    <p>Detail</p>
  `,
  directives: [MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES,ArticlesService] // <-----------
})
export class ArticlesDetailComponent {
  (...)
}
```

but it's not a component. That's why you have the error message...

Comment: Yes.Thank you. I don't know why I did it (((